# How to import tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = Sequential([layers.Input((3, 1)),
                    layers.LSTM(64),
                    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
                    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
                    layers.Dense(1)])

model.compile(loss='mse', 
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=100)
```

I was able to run this in google colab.
My problem is when I downloaded the python file from colab and tried to run it using vscode and Jupyter I received the following error:
"Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure"

I then commented out the above code, and the rest of my code worked fine, but when I imported TensorFlow as tf (still leaving the code commented out) and changed nothing else, I received the same error again.

How do I fix this? I have done pip install tensorflow, removed

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

changed all the layers. to tf.keras.layers. Nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions? New to TensorFlow, so I might be misunderstanding something.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are likely running out of memory or running a 32 bit python which has a limit of 4GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems tensorflow has not installed in your system properly. Please follow the step by steps mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link to install tensorflow. Attached the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050233/canceled-future-for-execute-request-message-before-replies-were-done) for your reference,

You can run the `.py` file in jupyter notebook as command `%run <filaname.py>` after uploading the file in the same environment of jupyter notebook and can use `<%load <filename.py>` to load the entire file in jupyter notebook.

It could be more easy if you download the file in `.ipynb` format from Google Colab and can directly open the file in the jupyter notebook after uploading it into same folder where Anaconda has installed.