# JAX: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done

Tags: optimization, scipy-optimize, newtons-method, jax

I have an optimization problem which I am trying to solve with Newton's method. To calculate jacobian matrix, I use jax.jacobian.

My objective function is called `calc_ms`. I use Newton's method to find roots:

```
def newton(f, x_0, tol=1e-5, max_iter=10):
    x = x_0
    q = lambda x: x - jnp.linalg.solve(jax.jacobian(f)(x), f(x))
    error = tol + 1
    n = 0
    while error > tol:
        n+=1
        if(n > max_iter):
            raise Exception('Max iteration reached without convergence')
        y = q(x)
        if(any(jnp.isnan(y))):
            raise Exception('Solution not found with NaN generated')
        error = jnp.linalg.norm(x - y)
        x = y
        print(f'iteration {n}, error = {error:.5f}')
    print('\n' + f'Result = {x} \n')
    return x
```

And then I use this function to solve the problem:

```
newton(lambda delta: calc_ms(delta, dist_util, food_exp, market_shares, corr_mat, n_stores), delta0).block_until_ready()
```

After some time kernel crashed with this error:

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050233/canceled-future-for-execute-request-message-before-replies-were-done

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9741, this error is coming from VSCode/Jupyter and possibly means you are running out of memory. Perhaps try running your code with smaller inputs?